# multipart-form-data, POST method, with multiples forms in the page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, multiple-forms

### Problem

I'm trying to make a **scraping** in a page using ***request's python lib***, however I'm getting errors (Like *Bad request* or *Method not allowed*).

- The page has two forms: one with get, and another one, with post (which I wish). I did pass values to text fields using 'data requests'.
- I don't wanna pass an image for the form, just a text field.
- I have six buttons in the form, for each button I have a different value.

---

#### HTML code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/page1" method="GET"> ... </form>
...
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/page2" method="POST"> 
  <input type="file" name="smiles_file">
  <input type="text" name="smiles_str">
  ...
  <button name="pred_type" type="submit" value="adme"> BT1 </button>
  <button name="pred_type" type="submit" value="toxicity"> BT2 </button>
</form>
```

---

#### Python3 code

```
#imports
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

#commmon vars
url = 'www.exampleurl.com/site'
hd  = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36"
}
dt  = {
'smiles_str': 'CC(=O)OC1=CC=CC=C1C(=O)O',
'pred_type': 'adme'
}

#scraping
with requests.Session() as rs:
    result = rs.get(url, data=dt, headers=hd)
    print ("Code: %s\nHTML\n%s" % (result.status_code, result.text))
```

---

#### EDIT

Using get:
 status_code: 405 (Method ... )
Using post:
 status_code: 400 (Bad request)

Comment: rs.get? should be rs.post

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reference to `/page1` nor `/page2` in your example, but the `rs.get` should probably be using the named parameter `params` instead of `data` and should correspond to the first form URL, while for the second form URL you'd need to use the `rs.post` method, where using data is okay.

Comment: I did use `post`, however I had error, so I tried with `get`, and got another error. I updated the question with respective errors. **Srry**.

About that: ***"I don't see a reference to /page1 nor /page2 in your example"***. Both forms are inside the page: 
_www.exampleurl.com/site_
so I have 7 buttons, 6 with values for the second form, and one to the fst form.

Comment: @PedroAugusto when you load `exampleurl.com/site` in your browser, and fill out `form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/page1" method="GET"` 's form fields, and press submit, the submitted multipart data will be added to as paramters to a GET request to `exampleurl.com/page1` by your browser. This is the behavior you need to replicate in your code.

Comment: The form that I really wanna is with post, I've tried use the page's url, and also the action url, and, in both cases, return me errors like i said before: . _Using get: status_code: 405 (Method ... ) Using post: status_code: 400 (Bad request)_

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. It seems that selenium does not work well on pages that work with js background. I'm using selenium, and I'm not having problems with it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. The wording of your answer doesn't make sense: you're stating that Selenium doesn't work well with certain JS features, and then you state that you're using Selenium, and have no problems with it. The second sentence does not logically follow from the first.